# Unable to install VirtualBox Guest Additions on Tails OS

Tags: tails, virtual-machine

I mounted Tails OS (booted through ISO file) on Virtual Box. The default OS display looks ugly and I couldn't mount Guest Additions through Optical drive as I mounted OS through the same. So, I uploaded Guest Additions.iso file in Google drive and downloaded in VM. When I try to install it, I got following error

[image: Guest Addition Installation Error]

Comment: Looks like you need to specify a path to install Vbox Guest Additions; i recommend using `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run '**VBoxLinuxAdditions.run**' file, not the autorun.sh.

Syntax: `bash VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`